# Cannot read property InnerHTML of null, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Pues este es el código HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Pig Game Simple Version</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="player-0-panel active">
            <div class="player-name" id="name-0">Player 1</div>
            <div class="player-score" id="score-0">43</div>
            <div class="player-current-box">
                <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                <div class="player-current-score" id="current-0">11</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="player-1-panel">
            <div class="player-name" id="name-1">Player 2</div>
            <div class="player-score" id="score-1">72</div>
            <div class="player-current-box">
                <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                <div class="player-current-score" id="current-1">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn-new"></i>New game</button>
        <button class="btn-roll"></i>Roll dice</button>
        <button class="btn-hold"></i>Hold</button>

        <div class="dice">5</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Y este el código en JS:

```js
var scores=[0,0];
var roundScore=0; 

var activePlayer=0;
var maximumPoints=100;

var dice=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) +1;

var score0=document.getElementById("current-0");
score0.innerHTML+="";
score0.innerHTML=dice.toString();
```

El caso es que con el debuggeador me dice que es incapaz de coger la etiqueta cuyo id es "current-0", me dice que es null, y claro ya de ahí me dice que `"Cannot read property InnerHTML of null"`. Y sinceramente, no veo el fallo por ningún sitio.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Carga el script hasta abajo, antes de `</body>`, porque si cargas primero el script el elemento al que quieres acceder aún no existe. Lo mejor sería colocar tu javascript en una función que se ejecute hasta que el DOM se haya cargado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo que estas llamado al codigo JS antes que se cargue el DOM.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  
  var scores=[0,0];
  var roundScore=0; 

  var activePlayer=0;
  var maximumPoints=100;

  var dice=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) +1;

  var score0=document.getElementById("current-0");
  score0.innerHTML+="";
  score0.innerHTML=dice.toString();

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes poner el código javascript dentro de window.onload

```
window.onload = function(){
var scores=[0,0];
var roundScore=0; 

var activePlayer=0;
var maximumPoints=100;

var dice=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) +1;

var score0=document.getElementById("current-0");
score0.innerHTML+="";
score0.innerHTML=dice.toString();
}
```